# SVN commands does not appear in context menu

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've just downloaded and installed SVN Tortoise, but no commands appear on the menu.
How is that possible?

Comment: What does appear in the menu? There probably won't be any commands, just a "TortoiseSVN" submenu.

Comment: Shell extensions usually silently fail with no errors. Try running the TortoiseSVN program from the Start Menu, this should show any errors that TortoiseSVN might have in starting up. In my case I needed to install a Visual C++ redistrubutal.

Answer (score 36):

Did you restart your machine?

**Update:**

I ran into the same problem myself! It happened when I installed version 1.6 over 1.5. When I restarted my machine, I found Tortoise entries in Start Menu but not via context menu. When I clicked on "Settings" an error message appeared. So, I uninstalled 1.6 and installed it anew. Now it's working again! Yes, available through context menu. I believe it's a bug.

Comment: I did.
When I try to execute the program from the "start" link, it even pops up a message  saying: "Tortoise SVN is integrated into the windows explorer.... right-click on any folder"

Comment: Did you try creating a new folder and then right-clicking on it?  Maybe you were clicking on a folder that TortoiseSVN doesn't have permission to put files in to.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue: upgraded to 1.6 over 1.5 and the contextual menu no more appeared. I had to uninstall, reboot, reinstall, reboot, and it worked. +1

Answer (score 33):

I was having the same issue on Windows 7 64-bit.  I reinstalled a number of times, but still could not see the context overlays in Explorer.  So I looked at the changelogs of TortoiseSVN and saw a recommendation to do a Repair install.  That solved my problem.

Comment: This fixed for me too. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 23):

Aside from first rebooting...

Are you running 64-bit or 32-bit Windows?  Tortoise runs as a shell extension so if your Windows OS is 64-bit and you installed the 32-bit version of Tortoise, you won't see the context menus.

On a side note. If you use a 32-bit tool like Total Commander in a 64-bit OS, and you want context menu extensions in both Explorer and Total Commander, you will actually have to install both the 32-bit and 64-bit version of Tortoise.

Comment: it use to be not an issue for me, i could install 32 bit version and i would have context menu, even though i was runing 64 bit win7, now i had to put 64 bit installer and repair it once for everything to work.

Answer (score 17):

I had the problem with my total commander and uninstall/reinstall several times, but the real "problem" is tortoise settings. From http://shalom.craimer.org/info/tech-journal/articles/653/The-context-menu-and-icons-for-TortoiseSVN-dont-appear-in-Total-Commander-but-the-do-appear-in-Windows-Explorer.-Why.html

- "Repair" in the TortoiseSVN's installer
- Restart
- In the TortoiseSVN settings (right-click in Explorer and select "Settings..." under "TortoiseSVN" in the context menu) -> "Icon Overlays" uncheck the checkbox labelled "Show overlays and context menus only in explorer."

Comment: You don't need to repair and restart (at least not always), as just unchecking the box will help, and if it is already unchecked then just toggle it by checking it and then unchecking it again.

Comment: I had the same problem. This TortoiseSVN option ("Show overlays and context menu only in explorer") was really the problem. When I unchecked it, the problem disappeared. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Repair install fixed the problem.

Comment: I repaired the installation and then the immediate reboot and it solved my issue too

Comment: Here is the post that explains why this is necessary:
http://tortoisesvn.net/majorupgrade.html

Comment: Repair install fixed things for me too, on 32-bit Windows XP.

Answer (score 4):

There is a long list of reasons why TSVN isnt working in your case. Your best bet is to have a look at the TortoiseSVN support list, failing that post a message to the list - they are a frendly bunch.

Ouch, looks like I cant post links yet - go to google-groups and look for TortoiseSVN, there are two lists tortoisesvn-dev and tortoisesvn, dont ask on the dev list you will be kindly asked to ask on the 'user' list

Answer (score 3):

If you miss your overlay icons, the regular 'SVN Update' and 'SVN Commit' commands, but instead have a 'SVN Upgrade working copy' command, you should click on it. The reason it appears is that TortoiseSVN has been upgraded and the working copy format has changed. This must from 1.7+ be upgraded manually. This will bring your commands and overlay-icons back.

Comment: This fixed me, just now.  Installed new version, repaired, rebooted - nothing else worked.  Thank you!

Comment: Same here, 'SVN upgrade working copy' needs to be run after upgrading Tortoise

Answer (score 2):

Incidentally I had this same problem on Windows Vista 64 bit.  Had to do the reinstall / reboot thing twice.  Installer was TortoiseSVN-1.6.12.20536-x64-svn-1.6.15.msi.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever I did - install/uninstall/reinstall/repair - nothing worked. Only after installing WANDisco Subversion Tortoise also started working.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I got around the problem:

On a fresh Windows 7 64-bit OS, I had some 32 bit applications plus the 64-bit totoisesvn application installed.

No icons in shell popupmenu!

To solve it I:

- uninstalled the 32 bit application that also used the menu,
- uninstalled the 64 bit svn
- used the regedit to manually remove any leftovers in the ShellIconoverlayIdentifyer hive
- rebooted
- and then reinstalling svn 64 bit svn,
- and then the 32-bit program.

Success! The svn menu items appeared (the 32 bit are still not visible though).

Conclusion: **Install the 64-bit apps before the 32-bit applications**.

Answer (score 2):

I had TortoiseSVN in Explorer context menu, but it was missed from UnrealCommander context menu.

I had to remove all entries of TortoiseSVN from registry manualy. Because repair installation had no effect for me.

But then after re-installing TortoiseSVN I had success.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem on my Windows 7 system.    Absolutely nothing in the context menu suggesting any presence of Tortoise SVN.     I did all the installs, re-installs, repairs, reboots, etc, etc, suggested above.

What finally fixed it for me was installing the 64 bit version.

Comment: Nice, the 64 bit edition is definitely required when running 64bit Windows 8+.

Answer (score 2):

You might be checked **"Hide Menus for unversioned path"** in Context Menu inside SVN settings. Uncheck the box and check or Press Shift + right click so that the context menu will appear.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to what others above have suggested, i encountered this problem and the root cause was 32 v 64 bit. I installed WANDisco Subversion - and in the process auto installed TortoiseSVN as well.

The version it installed was 32 bit however, and i had to uninstall that and reinstall the 64 bit version of TortoiseSVN separately.

Answer (score 1):

Using 32 bit Win XP I uninstalled rebooted then reinstalled and rebooted again and it fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

It can be fixed by repairing TortoiseSVN and immediate re-booting the OS. Make sure that your are using the correct version for your OS ( 32bit || 64 bit).

I faced the same problem with Window Server 2003 R2 when I upgraded to TortoiseSVN to version 
TortoiseSVN-1.6.12.20536-win32-svn-1.6.15. Now it's solved.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the problem of 'no context menu' after upgrading from 1.5 to 1.6 version. After first re-instal I had a new problem: 'no tortoise icons'.  I re-installed again tortoise 1.6.16 build 21511.

After reboot everything works properly. I have a win-32bit machine under XP.

Answer (score -1):

I was just chasing a red herring, maybe someone else experienced the same thing:

I thought the context menu wasn't appearing any more for moving versioned files. Turns out I was trying to move the files to a folder that I hadn't added to subversion yet. As soon as I added the folder in Tortoise, the context menu options re-appeared. Doh!

Answer (score -4):

1. Install
2. restart machine
3. repair install

It worked for me