# Download SVN for windows

Tags: svn

Every now and then I have a problem with SVN inside eclipse folder gets locked, I have to check out projects few times update and stuff like that . is there a SVN that I can use to commit files directly from console or windows folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the console [Slik Subversion](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download). From Windows explorer [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads).

Comment: @Neil Butterworth I have installed Tortoise SVN , nothing happens I get message Tortoise SVN is shell extension, right click on the folder ... when I do right click nothing new option comes in ..

Comment: @Gandalf If you right-click on a folder, one of the entries in the popup menu that appears should be TortoiseSVN.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth I've really tried several versions uinistalled installed nothing happens when I right click see http://i44.tinypic.com/8x6lx1.gif ty

Comment: I'm using windows 7 by the way

Comment: @Gandalf Not a lot I can do about it, I'm afraid - I suggest taking a look at the FAQ at http://tortoisesvn.net/faq, and if that fails post another question about it here. You'll need to give version information for your OS and for Tortoise.

Comment: @Gandalf also see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857564/svn-commands-does-not-appear-in-context-menu

Comment: Tortoise really is the best answer possible here, I personally think it's the best svn client, hands down. I'm not sure why it's not working for you, but it should be on that right-click menu. Try rebooting after install?

Comment: tnx neil your second link helped, I installed x86 bit version on x64 OS, so I just downloaded the x64 version

Comment: I'd prefer to download console client from collab.net. They update the binary packages more often than Silk does.

Comment: @Mr.Cat Slik has always worked well for me, which is why I recommended it.

Answer (score 1):

Which OS?  You have several options.  My favourites:

Windows: [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/)

Mac OSX: [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/)

Linux: [KDEsvn](http://kdesvn.alwins-world.de/)

Or any others off [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients).

For the command-line, you can use the "svn" binary directly from the SVN package for your system.  Or something like [Slik SVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download) on Windows.

Comment: Which OS? I would say the word "Windows" in the title is a bit of a give away.

Comment: As a developer I've learned never to assume the first thing that comes to mind.  For example, I have "windows" on my Mac - they're windows containing the contents of folders, but it's not the Windows OS.  Eclipse is a multi-platform IDE, therefore the OP might be wanting to commit changes from a folder window instead of the IDE.  Plus "console" is not a commonly-used term for the Windows command-line.  And to be particularly pedantic, "windows" != "Windows" (note the case difference.)

Comment: and the reason for the downvote please?  Does this somehow not answer the question?